# Difference between IntStream.rangeClosed(x,y) and IntStream.range(x,y+1)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

`IntStream.range(x,y)` would return a stream from ***x(inclusive)*** and ***y(exclusive)***.
`IntStream.rangeClosed(x,y)` would return a stream from ***x(inclusive)*** and ***y(inclusive)***.

I expected `rangeClosed(x,y)` to invoke `range(x,y-1)` or `range(x,y)` to invoke `rangeClosed(x,y-1)`. But while looking at the source code for `range` it was like:

```java
if (startInclusive >= endExclusive) {
    return empty();
} else {
    return StreamSupport.intStream(
    new Streams.RangeIntSpliterator(startInclusive, endExclusive, false /*not closed*/), false);
}
```

The `rangeClosed` also had a very similar implementation rather than `range(x,y+1)`. The only difference was that the third argument to `Streams.RangeIntSpliterator` was `true` instead of `false` denoting that the range is closed.

This boolean is then used to initialize `int last` field in `Streams.RangeIntSpliterator` class and the below comment is mentioned against it:

> 1 if the range is closed and the last element has not been traversed
> Otherwise, 0 if the range is open, or is a closed range and all
> elements have been traversed

Why is such an implementation necessary instead of `range` simply calling `rangeClosed` or the other way round? Is there any significant difference between calling `rangeClosed(x,y)` instead of `range(x,y+1)` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even though there aren't any differences in the normal scenario, it would cause an issue when the input to the methods are min/max limits of `Integer`.

Assuming that `rangeClosed(x,y)` invokes `range(x,y+1)`. If you are invoking `rangeClosed(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)`, then instead of the expected number of iterations (2147483648), the actual number of iterations would be 0, as `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` would result in an overflow and an empty stream would be returned.

Similar overflow would cause the result to be different in case if an input is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: Open and close intervals are represented using `(open, close]`. Note that `Math.addExact(y, 1)` would fail fast and should be used ideally.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Sorry, but I am not able to get the point you were trying to convey. Is it like `range(x , Math.addExact(y, 1))` would result in an exception rather than an incorrect result when compared to the `range(x, y+1)` incase when `y` is `MAX_VALUE` ?

Comment: Yes indeed. Try `range(0 , Math.addExact(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1))`, it will result in an exception.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Yes. But still the result of that is different from invoking `rangeClosed(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)` (which would have worked without exception). My question was more inclined towards why one method was not calling the other in terms of implementation.